# How can I install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Here is the problem:

I have a *requirements.txt* file that looks like:

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.0
Django==1.3
Fabric==1.2.0
Jinja2==2.5.5
PyYAML==3.09
Pygments==1.4
SQLAlchemy==0.7.1
South==0.7.3
amqplib==0.6.1
anyjson==0.3
...
```

I have a local archive directory containing all the packages + others.

I have created a new [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) with

```
bin/virtualenv testing
```

Upon activating it, I tried to install the packages according to *requirements.txt* from the local archive directory.

```
source bin/activate
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt -f file:///path/to/archive/
```

I got some output that seems to indicate that the installation is fine:

```
Downloading/unpacking Fabric==1.2.0 (from -r ../testing/requirements.txt (line 3))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Fabric
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    warning: no files found matching 'fabfile.py'
Downloading/unpacking South==0.7.3 (from -r ../testing/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package South
....
```

But a later check revealed that none of the packages are installed properly. I cannot import the packages, and none are found in the site-packages directory of my virtualenv. So what went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `--no-index` so it does not even look at PyPI?

Comment: You've snipped the error message. It's generally near the bottom.

Comment: You could use the file paths instead of the package names, it means you'll have to change the requirements.txt file, but keep the pip install command the same.

Comment: surprised nobody else linked but https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Comment: I had to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40378520/348162

Comment: I'm wondering... did your local archive contain the exact same versions of the packages that were specified in `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 1117, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///tmp/packages
```

`--no-index` - Ignore package index (only look at `--find-links` URLs instead).

`-f, --find-links <URL>` - If `<URL>` is a URL or a path to an HTML file, then parse for links to archives. If `<URL>` is a local path or a `file://` URL that's a directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

Comment: **Information on  `--no-index` from command pip help install** `--no-index` Ignore package index (only looking at `--find-links` URLs instead).  **Information on  `--find-links` from command pip help install** `-f`, `--find-links <url>` If a url or path to an html file, then parse for links to archives. If a local path or file:// url that's a directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

Comment: // , This could be a very elegant solution, especially given the eternal struggle with vendorizing: http://bitprophet.org/blog/2012/06/07/on-vendorizing/

Comment: One caution with this is you may `pip install <some_module>` without using `requirements.txt` but that will not update `requirements.txt`. An alternative might be updating a docker such that it lists all the pip install commands that are run to install dependencies.

Comment: i tried this `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` when inside the activated venv enviroment. things installed smoothly but when i do pip list it does not show that packages, when I am in the active venv or even after deactivate venv. also not able to use that packages. dont know what's wrong here

Comment: Are you sure ``python`` refers to the activated environment's python executable (``$ which python``)?

Comment: Just a heads up: This will work as long as there's not `git+ssh` requirement in the `requirements.txt`. For the `git+ssh` pip will still try to fetch the package

Comment: same problem with git+https://... is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 2277):

This works for everyone:

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

**Explanation:**

> -r, --requirement < filename >

Install from the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.

Comment: I realize this answer doesn't address the original question, but it answers the question I had when I found this on Google...

Comment: for those who like to know what they type, the -r in the command just means "install from a requirements file", and is a shortcut for --requirement

Comment: When I want to upgrade a package (e.g. Django), I change the version in my requirements.txt file and then run `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`. This detects the change, upgrades the package, and leaves everything else alone.

Comment: pip freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: while this usually works, a couple subtleties makes it fail. If any install failed for the packages in `requirements.txt`, none of them will be installed. If a required module imports a dependency during its installation (instead of just listing it as a requirement), it will fail even if the dependency precedes it in the list of dependencies, causing all modules to fail. It is probably a bug to import a dependent module during installation, but it is also possibly unexpected that the dependencies listed in `requirements.txt` aren't installed sequentially, but all at once.

Comment: In an app that has a `Django` backend and `Angular` frontend, should the `requirements.txt` file be in the root directory (and run there with `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt`) or should it be in the backend folder where files such as `manage.py` are located?

Comment: @ReemAl-Assaf it doesn't matter that much. Some people prefer to keep a `package.json` and `requirements.txt` in the top level directories for the entire project, or in the sub directories where language specific things take over. It's your choice at this point.

Comment: Does anyone know the behavior of this command when the requirements.txt file is empty? Would it throw an error or just simply not do anything.  I am unable to verify from my system.

Answer (score 191):

For virtualenv to install all files in the *requirements.txt* file.

1. cd to the directory where *requirements.txt* is located
2. activate your virtualenv
3. run:  `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your shell

Comment: "pyenv virtualenv pip install requirements.txt not working" for the sake of Google...

Comment: pip3 install -r requirements.txt worked for me in venv

Comment: `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: How do you do "activate your virtualenv"?

Answer (score 78):

I had a similar problem. I tried this:

```
    pip install -U -r requirements.txt
```

*(-U = update if it had already installed)*

But the problem continued. I realized that some of generic libraries for development were missed.

```
    sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

I don't know if this would help you.

Answer (score 57):

Use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

For further details, please check the help option:

```
pip install --help
```

We can find the option '-r' -

> -r, --requirement     Install from the given requirements file. This option can be
> used multiple times.

Further information on some commonly used pip install options (this is the help option on the pip install command):

[image]

Also the above is the complete set of options. Please use `pip install --help` for the complete list of options.

Answer (score 36):

**Short answer**

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

or in another form:

```
python -m pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

**Explanation**

Here, `-r` is short form of `--requirement` and it asks the `pip` to install from the given `requirements` file.

`pip` will start installation only after checking the availability of all listed items in the `requirements` file and it won't start installation even if one `requirement` is unavailable.

One workaround to install the available packages is installing listed packages one by one. Use the following command for that. A red color warning will be shown to notify you about the unavailable packages.

```
cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install
```

To ignore comments (lines starting with a `#`) and blank lines, use:

```
cat requirements.txt | cut -f1 -d"#" | sed '/^\s*$/d' | xargs -n 1 pip install
```

Answer (score 30):

First of all, create a virtual environment.

In Python 3.6

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

In Python 2.7

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

Then activate the environment and install all the packages available in the *requirement.txt* file.

```
source <path/to/new/virtualenv>/bin/activate
pip install -r <path/to/requirement.txt>
```

Comment: Thanks. For windows user, to activate environment use this command : `<path-to-virtualenv>/Scripts/activate.bat`. To deactivate environment, use this : `<path-to-virtualenv>/Scripts/deactivate.bat`.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 25):

Often, you will want a fast install from local archives, without probing PyPI.

First, download the archives that fulfill your requirements:

```
$ pip install --download <DIR> -r requirements.txt
```

Then, install using `–find-links` and `–no-index`:

```
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=[file://]<DIR> -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: `no such option: --download`

Comment: In newer versions of pip `pip install --download` has to be `pip download`.

Answer (score 18):

I work with a lot of systems that have been mucked by developers "following directions they found on the Internet". It is extremely common that your `pip` and your `python` are not looking at the same paths/site-packages. For this reason, when I encounter oddness I start by doing this:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

That is a *happy system*.

Below is an *unhappy system*. (Or at least it's a blissfully ignorant system that causes others to be unhappy.)

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

$ which pip pip2 pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

It is *unhappy* because `pip` is (python3.6 and) using `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` while `python` is (python2.7 and) using `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

When I want to make sure I'm installing requirements to the *right* python, I do this:

```
$ which -a python python2 python3
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python2
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ /usr/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You've heard, "If it ain't broke, don't try to fix it." The DevOps version of that is, "If you didn't break it and you can work around it, don't try to fix it."

Answer (score 15):

**Installing requirements.txt file inside virtual env with Python 3:**

I had the same issue. I was trying to install the *requirements.txt* file inside a virtual environment. I found the solution.

Initially, I created my virtualenv in this way:

```
virtualenv -p python3 myenv
```

Activate the environment using:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Now I installed the *requirements.txt* file using:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Installation was successful and I was able to import the modules.

Comment: I faced this issue while installing the requirements file inside a virtual environment. I have now modified my response to address the issue

Comment: Using Anaconda Python 3.6 on Windows, I had to do `virtualenv -p python myenv`, `myenv\Scripts\activate.bat`, `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Actually, on the contrary, this seems like the only answer that _does_ answer the part of the question about installing locally defined deps in `requirements.txt` to a virtualenv. Unless I am missing something? Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

On windows Using this

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

On linux pc we have python2 and also python3 so most time `pip` is regarded as

Python2

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Python 3

```
pip3 install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

- Create virtual environment `python3 -m venv virtual-env` (For windows use python instead of python3)
- Activate your virtual environment `source virtual-env/bin/activate`
- Now install requirements `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 10):

```
pip install --user -r requirements.txt
```

OR

```
pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: is it possible to specify `--user` inside `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 9):

Use `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`  But make sure the requirements.txt file has been pulled from origin and not added to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, this can lead to less format-related path issues, if you have

> c:\folder\subfolder\requirements.txt

```
cd c:\folder\subfolder 
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

I have solved with running the below command:

```
py -m pip install ./requirements.txt
```

the above command will install all dependencies and libraries for the Django project.