# How to install packages offline?

Tags: python, pip, freebsd, easy-install, python-requests

What's the best way to download a python package and its dependencies from pypi for offline installation on another machine? Is there any easy way to do this with pip or easy_install? I'm trying to install the requests library on a FreeBSD box that is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Related: [How to pip install packages according to requirements.txt from a local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7225900/95735)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If the package is on PYPI, download it and its dependencies to some local directory.
E.g.

```
$ mkdir /pypi && cd /pypi
$ ls -la
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff   237954 Apr 19 11:31 Flask-WTF-0.6.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff   389741 Feb 22 17:10 Jinja2-2.6.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff    70305 Apr 11 00:28 MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff  2597214 Apr 10 18:26 SQLAlchemy-0.7.6.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff  1108056 Feb 22 17:10 Werkzeug-0.8.2.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff   488207 Apr 10 18:26 boto-2.3.0.tar.gz
  -rw-r--r--   1 pavel  staff   490192 Apr 16 12:00 flask-0.9-dev-2a6c80a.tar.gz
```

Some packages may have to be archived into similar looking tarballs by hand. I do it a lot when I want a more recent (less stable) version of something. Some packages aren't on PYPI, so same applies to them.

Suppose you have a properly formed Python application in `~/src/myapp`. `~/src/myapp/setup.py` will have `install_requires` list that mentions one or more things that you have in your `/pypi` directory. Like so:

```
  install_requires=[
    'boto',
    'Flask',
    'Werkzeug',
    # and so on
```

If you want to be able to run your app with all the necessary dependencies while still hacking on it, you'll do something like this:

```
$ cd ~/src/myapp
$ python setup.py develop --always-unzip --allow-hosts=None --find-links=/pypi
```

This way your app will be executed straight from your source directory. You can hack on things, and then rerun the app without rebuilding anything.

If you want to install your app and its dependencies into the current python environment, you'll do something like this:

```
$ cd ~/src/myapp
$ easy_install --always-unzip --allow-hosts=None --find-links=/pypi .
```

In both cases, the build will fail if one or more dependencies aren't present in `/pypi` directory. It won't attempt to promiscuously install missing things from Internet.

I highly recommend to invoke `setup.py develop ...` and `easy_install ...` within an active [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) to avoid contaminating your global Python environment. It is (virtualenv that is) pretty much the way to go. Never install anything into global Python environment.

If the machine that you've built your app has same architecture as the machine on which you want to deploy it, you can simply tarball the entire virtual environment directory into which you `easy_install`-ed everything. Just before tarballing though, you must make the virtual environment directory relocatable (see [--relocatable](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#making-environments-relocatable) option). **NOTE:** the destination machine needs to have the same version of Python installed, and also any C-based dependencies your app may have must be preinstalled there too (e.g. say if you depend on [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), then libpng, libjpeg, etc must be preinstalled).

Comment: Instead of `--allow-hosts=None` you could use the switch `--no-index`

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to create a properly formed Python application?

Comment: @PrabhjotRai please refer to https://packaging.python.org/distributing/

Answer (score 507):

#### On the system that has access to internet

The pip `download` command lets you download packages without installing them:

```bash
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

(In previous versions of pip, this was spelled `pip install --download -r requirements.txt`.)

#### On the system that has no access to internet

Then you can use

```bash
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ -r requirements.txt
```

to install those downloaded modules, without accessing the network.

Comment: problem with this is that the dependencies might have other dependencies and those won't be downloaded.

Comment: [Snake basket](https://github.com/prezi/snakebasket) (built on top of pip) will download the dependencies' dependencies as well.

Comment: @vikki Not true, "pip install --download" also downloads dependencies, so the above commands will work correctly even if your requirements have additional dependencies. Snake basket may do other useful things (never used it), but it's definitely not needed for that reason.

Comment: `pip install --download -r requirements.txt` only downloads the dependencies listed in requirements.txt, if those dependencies have other requirements e.g in setup.py, pip won't fetch those, sb adds that feature. e.g if a project requires sphinx `pip -d` will only fetch sphinx but not jinja, pygments and docutils (which are needed by sphinx). These will only be fetched once you run setup.py, but since this is supposed to be for offline use you won't have a working connection at the time you run setup.py and the installation will fail citing unmet dependencies as the issue.

Comment: @vikki I understand what you are saying, but I am telling you that it is not true :-) You should actually go try it before you post the same assertion again. I just put "pytest" in a requirements.txt, ran "pip install --download . -r requirements.txt", and it downloaded sdists for both pytest and its setup.py dependency, "py".

Comment: Okay I'll try again. I could have sworn I tried it today with sphinx, and pip on its own didn't pick up sphinx's deps, only after adding sb did it download them. I'll investigate further.

Comment: After reading [this](http://engineering.prezi.com/blog/2013/04/19/snakebasket/) I now understand that snakebasket only forces pip to inspect each download's `requirements.txt` and download whatever is listed. Some projects will list their dependencies in `requirements.txt` and the list will vary from that which is in setup.py. [django-oscar](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar) is an example.

Comment: I think this is the more correct/simple answer. It takes care of the requirements without an intervening step.

Comment: Like @vikki, for me this also didn't download the entire dependency graph.  However, I still appreciate the answer, as it was only one package that was missing, and I just explicitly added it to requirements.txt.

Comment: I think it should be: `--find-links file:/path/to/some/dir/` and you should download and install with the same version of pip - otherwise it might fail

Comment: `pip download -r requirements.txt` this is true.

Comment: Note that `pip download <package>` downloads dependencies as well.

Comment: i added `--no-deps` to the command, otherwise it will try to find some dependencies online (which was not possible)

Comment: Can you somehow generate the `requirements.txt` for a certain Python version? Let's say, I have Python 3.8.2 (not the newest version). I want the package `numpy`. How do I know which version I need to download for my Python version? Do the Python versions on the online and offline computer have to be the same?

Comment: @stackprotector, yes, I discovered that it's very helpful to run `python --version` on the offline computer before attempting this procedure! Then, on your online computer, per the [pip download docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/), you can run (for Python 3.8.2):
`pip download --python-version=3.8.2 --only-binary=:all: -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 186):

If you want install python libs and their dependencies offline, finish following these steps on a machine with the same os, network connected, and python installed:

1) Create a `requirements.txt` file with similar content (Note - these are the libraries you wish to download):

```
Flask==0.12
requests>=2.7.0
scikit-learn==0.19.1
numpy==1.14.3
pandas==0.22.0
```

One option for creating the requirements file is to use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.  This will list all libraries in your environment.  Then you can go in to `requirements.txt` and remove un-needed ones.

2) Execute command `mkdir wheelhouse && pip download -r requirements.txt -d wheelhouse` to download libs and their dependencies to directory `wheelhouse`

3) Copy requirements.txt into `wheelhouse` directory

4) Archive wheelhouse into `wheelhouse.tar.gz` with `tar -zcf wheelhouse.tar.gz wheelhouse`

Then upload `wheelhouse.tar.gz` to your target machine:

1) Execute `tar -zxf wheelhouse.tar.gz` to extract the files

2) Execute `pip install -r wheelhouse/requirements.txt --no-index --find-links wheelhouse` to install the libs and their dependencies

Comment: but following your instruction, when I `pip install` in the end, it says: ERROR: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ..`

Comment: @DennisLi what's your python and pip version?

Comment: I figured this out, that is because pip can't find the specific version of the pandas package in my requirements.txt, as I used pip3 to install the pandas 0.2

Comment: same happened to me. with pip3 i received same error message mentioned. maybe it only works with python2 only.

Comment: @chaokunyang Thanks a lot. Could you please also give me a hint how I can embed this process into the `setup.py` so when installing my own package, it goes and installs all the deps as well ?

Comment: One problem with this workflow is different architectures. If you run `pip download ...` on a mac, you will have `*-macosx*.whl` files that are unusable on e.g. linux

Comment: Hi, I got the following error in the step 1 of target machine:-  "tar: Must specify one of -c, -r, -t, -u, -x".

Comment: @DennisLi Were you able to solve this problem? I keep getting this error on some of my packages and it gives me a ton of problems creating the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 25):

Let me go through the process step by step:

1. On a computer connected to the internet, create a folder.

```
   $ mkdir packages
   $ cd packages
```

2. open up a command prompt or shell and execute the following command:

   *Suppose the package you want is* `tensorflow`

   `$ pip download tensorflow`
3. Now, on the target computer, copy the `packages` folder and apply the following command

```
  $ cd packages
  $ pip install 'tensorflow-xyz.whl' --no-index --find-links '.'
```

Note that the `tensorflow-xyz.whl` must be replaced by the original name of the required package.

Answer (score 19):

offline python. for doing this I use virtualenv (isolated Python environment)

1) install virtualenv 
online with pip:

```
pip install virtualenv --user
```

or offline with whl: go to this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) , download last version (.whl or tar.gz) and install that with this command:

```
pip install virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user
```

by using `--user` you don't need to use `sudo pip…`.

2) use virtualenv

on online machine select a directory with terminal `cd` and run this code:

```
python -m virtualenv myenv
cd myenv
source bin/activate
pip install Flask
```

after installing all the packages, you have to generate a `requirements.txt` so while your virtualenv is active, write

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

open a new terminal and create another env like `myenv2`.

```
python -m virtualenv myenv2
cd myenv2
source bin/activate
cd -
ls
```

now you can go to your offline folder where your `requirements.txt` and `tranferred_packages` folder are in there. download the packages with following code and put all of them to `tranferred_packages` folder.

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

take your offline folder to offline computer and then

```
python -m virtualenv myenv2
cd myenv2
source bin/activate
cd -
cd offline
pip install --no-index --find-links="./tranferred_packages" -r requirements.txt
```

what is in the folder offline  [requirements.txt , tranferred_packages {Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz, ...}]

check list of your package

```
pip list
```

note: as we are in 2017 it is better to use python 3. you can create python 3 virtualenv with this command.

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Comment: There appears to be steps missing or "obfuscated" here, I would expect to see a 'deactivate' and then 'pip freeze'... cd offline and ./tranferred_packages appears from nowhere - clearly this needs a cleanup?

Comment: maybe, but you should consider 'I wanted a brief post' , 'that process was complex and I couldn't write every step (that only possible in YouTube)'.

Comment: This is the best answer imho. Helped a lot

Comment: This would be the best answer if it said anything at all on how to setup the tranferred_packages folder. Without crucial steps, -1

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. And i had to make it install the same way, we do from pypi.

I did the following things:

1. Make a directory to store all the packages in the machine that have internet access.

   ```
   mkdir -p /path/to/packages/
   ```
2. Download all the packages to the path

> Edit: You can also try:
>
> ```
> python3 -m pip wheel --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -w /path/to/packages
> ```

```
pip download -r requirements.txt -d /path/to/packages

Eg:- ls /root/wheelhouse/  # **/root/wheelhouse** is my **/path/to/packages/**
total 4524
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   16667 May 23  2017 incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   34713 Sep  1 10:21 attrs-18.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3088398 Oct 15 14:41 Twisted-18.9.0.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  133356 Jan 28 15:58 chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  154154 Jan 28 15:58 certifi-2018.11.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   57987 Jan 28 15:58 requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   58594 Jan 28 15:58 idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  118086 Jan 28 15:59 urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   47229 Jan 28 15:59 tqdm-4.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    7922 Jan 28 16:13 constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  164706 Jan 28 16:14 zope.interface-4.6.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  573841 Jan 28 16:14 setuptools-40.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   37638 Jan 28 16:15 Automat-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   37905 Jan 28 16:15 hyperlink-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   52311 Jan 28 16:15 PyHamcrest-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   10586 Jan 28 16:15 six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

3. Tar the packages directory and copy it to the Machine that doesn't have internet access. Then do,

   ```
   cd /path/to/packages/
   tar -cvzf packages.tar.gz .  # not the . (dot) at the end
   ```

Copy the **packages.tar.gz** into the destination machine that doesn't have internet access.

4. In the machine that doesn't have internet access, do the following  (Assuming you copied the tarred packages to **/path/to/package/** in the current machine)

   ```
   cd /path/to/packages/
   tar -xvzf packages.tar.gz
   mkdir -p $HOME/.config/pip/
   vi $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
   ```

and paste the following content inside and save it.

```
[global]
timeout = 10
find-links = file:///path/to/package/
no-cache-dir = true
no-index = true
```

5. Finally, i suggest you use, some form of `virtualenv` for installing the packages.

   ```
   virtualenv -p python2 venv # use python3, if you are on python3
   source ./venv/bin/activate
   pip install <package>
   ```

You should be able to download all the modules that are in the directory **/path/to/package/**.

Note: I only did this, because i couldn't add options or change the way we install the modules. Otherwise i'd have done

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you clarify the last paragraph? To me it says that your pip.conf approach is just an alternative to doing "pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ -r requirements.txt" ? Why is that you could not launch this command?

Comment: @Kiteloopdesign It's been sometime, but i guess it was because we had no control over the `pip install` call

Answer (score 9):

## For another platform with another Python version

To download python packages for another platform, you need the `--platform` parameter in combination with the `--only-binary=:all:` parameter. To also define the Python version of the target system, use the `--python-version` parameter.

Example scenario: You are on Windows and want to download `numpy` for a Linux system that uses Python 3.9. Use the following command to download `numpy` with all its dependencies for your target system:

```
pip download --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --python-version=3.9 numpy
```

To install `numpy` on your target system, copy the downloaded files to it and install the package via:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/package/files numpy
```

Instead of defining a particular package name, you can also use a requirements file for both commands. Just replace the package name by `-r requirements.txt`, for example.

Comment: FYI can use sysconfig.get_platform() to get the value for --platform with all hyphens `-` and periods `.` replaced with underscore `_`

Answer (score 8):

Download the [tarball](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tarball/master), transfer it to your FreeBSD machine and extract it, afterwards run `python setup.py install` and you're done!

EDIT: Just to add on that, you can also install the tarballs with pip now.

Comment: What about all the dependencies? What's the best way to resolve them? Do I need to install the dependencies manually as well?

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunatly the only way I know.

Answer (score 7):

Using `wheel` compiled packages.

bundle up:

```
$ tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/wheelhouse-XXXXX)
$ pip wheel -r requirements.txt --wheel-dir=$tempdir
$ cwd=`pwd`
$ (cd "$tempdir"; tar -cjvf "$cwd/bundled.tar.bz2" *)
```

copy tarball and install:

```
$ tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/wheelhouse-XXXXX)
$ (cd $tempdir; tar -xvf /path/to/bundled.tar.bz2)
$ pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --upgrade --no-index --no-deps $tempdir/*
```

Note `wheel` binary packages are not across machines.

More ref. here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installation-bundles

Comment: I had issues with bundling up on machine with Python 3.6 and extracting on another with Python 3.5: "_<package>.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform_". The source and destination versions might be required to match with some packages.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows I have used below things

**Internet Connection**

1.Create directory with any name.I have created with "repo"

2.Download libraries using below command (it will download not install)

pip download libraray_name -d"C:\repo"

```
pip download openpyxl -d"C:\repo"
```

3. Then you will find multiple .whl extension files
4. copy all the filename in requirements.txt
   [image]

**No Internet Connection**

5. Now Move this folder and files to PC where no internet connection and run the below command.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=C:\repo --no-index
```

You can read the detailed blog [Link](https://medium.com/p/33d9caa0ee8f)

Answer (score 5):

As a continues to @chaokunyang answer, I want to put here the script I write that does the work:

1. Write a "requirements.txt" file that specifies the libraries you want to pack.
2. Create a tar file that contains all your libraries (see the Packer script).
3. Put the created tar file in the target machine and untar it.
4. run the Installer script (which is also packed into the tar file).

"requirements.txt" file

```
docker==4.4.0
```

Packer side: file name: "create-offline-python3.6-dependencies-repository.sh"

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script follows the steps described in this link:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646354/8808983

LIBRARIES_DIR="python3.6-wheelhouse"

if [ -d ${LIBRARIES_DIR} ]; then
    rm -rf ${LIBRARIES_DIR}/*
else
    mkdir ${LIBRARIES_DIR}
fi

pip download -r requirements.txt -d ${LIBRARIES_DIR}

files_to_add=("requirements.txt" "install-python-libraries-offline.sh")

for file in "${files_to_add[@]}"; do
    echo "Adding file ${file}"
    cp "$file" ${LIBRARIES_DIR}
done

tar -cf ${LIBRARIES_DIR}.tar ${LIBRARIES_DIR}
```

Installer side: file name: "install-python-libraries-offline.sh"

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script follows the steps described in this link:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646354/8808983

# This file should run during the installation process from inside the libraries directory, after it was untared:
# pythonX-wheelhouse.tar -> untar -> pythonX-wheelhouse
# |
# |--requirements.txt
# |--install-python-libraries-offline.sh


pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links .
```

Comment: One more thing that helped when installing the packages in virtual environment is adding this command just after creating the environment. `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` . Not doing this led to spurious errors.

Answer (score 3):

For Pip 8.1.2 you can use `pip download -r requ.txt` to download packages to your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Download the wheel file (for example dlb-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl) from Pypi and

```
pip install dlb-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
```