# Download python package with dependencies without installing

Tags: python, python-2.7, package-managers

I need to download a python package with all its dependencies without installing, sneaker-net it to a computer without connection to the internet, and install it there. For example, I want to install buildbot, lettuce, etc.

The computer is a Windows 7 machine, using Python 2.7.
If the package has native extensions, I can build them on the computer.

Comment: Related: [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11091623/11942268)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `pip`, with the `--download` option, which will download the main package and its dependencies, without installing them.

```
pip install --download="/path/to/downloaded/files" sneaker-net
```

And use these files one the local machine with:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=<DIR on local machine> sneaker-net
```

See [`pip` documentation `--download` for fast & local installs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#fast-local-installs). You can use `pip` on Windows with cygwin for example.

Comment: I'm trying to run `pip` on Windows, does it only work with cygwin?

Comment: @dkrikun See this question for more information on pip on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows Very useful tool, it's always useful to have it installed :)

Comment: For those, who read this answer in 2018 or later: modern pip can do `pip download <package>` for you

Comment: I want to download and store the packages on a work network location. The reason is that proxy issues always plague all attempts at using Git and pip. Thus I want to have them downloaded by IT once and then stored on a local network location from which we shall download and install them.

Comment: *Warning*: `pip download` involves, somewhat unexpectedly, [execution of the remote code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52486985/674039). It should only be used if you trust the package and all its dependencies.

Comment: new version: pip3 download sneaker-net ----- this will download into the current directory