# Python Package Install- identify dependent packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-install

My python server does not have access to Internet so I have to send packages through email and then pip install pointing to these packages.

Problem is it fails because some of the dependent package, it is looking for does not exist. So I have to send this new package as well and install this one first.

Is there a way to know all the dependent packages which are needed for this install so that I can download all of them and send it on my python machine?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092927/download-python-package-with-dependencies-without-installing). `pip --download` does the job

Edit:
So the correct syntax is

```
pip download ...
```

Check [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) for options and use cases.

Comment: This option does not exist anymore.

Comment: When did they remove it? I also need to install packages in a server offline and I believe I have used pip --download in the last month or so...

Comment: The correct syntax is `pip download` and it [still exists](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/).

Comment: The `--download` option was [removed in pip v8.0.0 (2016)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id538). A top-level download subcommand was added instead.

Comment: Right! my bad, I was too quick to assume --download was still the way. Thank you both for clarifying!