# Can I install Django as offline in Windows 7?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm new to Python and PyCharm. When I'm trying to make a Django project, it shows an error box. Later I found that it's due to no availability of internet connection on my PC.

Is there any way to install Django as offline in Windows 7 PC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to perform an offline installation of Django:

1. Download a Django release on a machine with internet connection from https://github.com/django/django/releases
2. As of Django 1.11, [pytz is a dependency](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/#pytz-is-a-required-dependency-and-support-for-settings-time-zone-none-is-removed]). Download the latest wheel [from pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz)
3. Transfer the downloaded files to the offline PC
4. Install pytz: `pip install pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl` (update filename as appropriate)
5. Install Django: `pip install <release-name>.zip`

For example, if you downloaded `django-1.9.2.zip` from Github, you can install it by running

```
pip install django-1.9.2.zip
```

Comment: Where i should put those files in offline pc ? Is it need any special directory ?

Comment: You can put the file anywhere on your PC, as long as you can `pip install` the file

Comment: Ty...i jst put the path of zip file...it' worked

Comment: with django 1.9.4 and 1.9.5 it did not work

Comment: @Alasdair, in the link you attached for pytz dependency documentation, it says "To simplify Django’s timezone handling, pytz is now a required dependency. It’s automatically installed along with Django." So we shouldn't have to install it separately in the Django 1.11 offline install process?

Comment: @Amacelia pytz is automatically installed if you do `pip install django`. This question is about trying to install Django without an internet connection, in which case you have to download pytz as well. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/113962) suggests, you can download Django and its requirements with `pip download Django`