# Offline installation of Django

Tags: python, django, pip

As in:
[Can I install Django as offline in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144184/can-i-install-django-as-offline-in-windows-7)
... I am trying to install Django from a file.

My RHEL 7 is in a closed network. From another computer I have fetched version 2.0.1 from https://github.com/django/django/releases.

running install-command results in:

```
pip3.6 install django-2.0.1.tar.gz
Processing ./django-2.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting pytz (from Django==2.0.1)

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from Django==2.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytz (from Django==2.0.1)
```

The error corresponds to the fact, that my system does not have access through the proxy. How can I do the install without the need of access to outside world?

The possible duplicate: [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation) didn't mention pytz-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the `pytz` requirement. For example download the wheel [from PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz).

Then install the wheel before Django

```
pip install pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pip install django-2.0.1.tar.gz
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/113962) on the duplicate question suggests, you can download Django and its requirement(s) by running:

```
pip download django
```