# Is there a way to install matplotlib offline on linux?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have been trying to install matplotlib on offline linux system without much success.
I have tried:
`python2.7 setup.py build`

It then tries the following:
`Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz`

The same happens with `setup.py install`.
How can I get it to install without an internet connection?
I use Python 2.7.12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Matplotlib pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib) package index and download the appropriate file for your system.
Then use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools build-essential 
$ pip install wheel_file.whl
```

you might have to use `sudo` with this command.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<dir>/python2.7/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

same error with or without sudo.

Comment: You should have `python-setuptools` and `build-essential` in your system to install with this way.

Answer (score -1):

Download the matploitdb wheel 
 "http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib"

Then do,

`pip install matploitdb_wheel.whl`

Comment: I want the installation on a linux system. All the wheels you mentioned are windows wheels.