# Copying python applications to servers without internet connection

Tags: python, deployment, pip

Currently I have a production server that doesn't have any connection to the internet (connections are not allowed).

Since I have a massive number of applications which use tons of packages, I need to figure out the best way to deploy without pip or downloading every whl package. Which would be the most appropriate way to replicate the virtualenv for other servers?

What would be the proper approach for that situation?

EDIT: Would `pip2.7 wheel --wheel-dir=/path/ package` do the job?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command solved:

```
pip2.7 wheel --wheel-dir=/project/whls/ package
```

I packaged everything, uploaded to the server and executed the command

`cd /projects/whls/;  pip install *`

Worked perfectly.