# How do I import python modules into Pycharm offline

Tags: python, pycharm

I have some offline computers which I cannot connect to the Internet. Not surprisingly, several of the modules are outdated. How do I update them and also add new ones?

I am envisioning downloading something from the Internet, putting it on a flash drive, then loading it somehow into Pycharm. This question is about the first and last steps.

Pycharm 2018, Windows 10

Comment: You can install with wheel file, open CMD and type -> `pip install D:/some-folder/your-file.whl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the downloaded packages from somewhere that connected to internet then store it as  via

```
# in case of just single package
$ pip install <package> --download <path>/offline_packages

# incase you need a list of pakages
$ pip install --download <path>/offline_packages -r requirements.txt
```

Tranfer the  to your machine (by anyway you can)

Install these packages to your current Pycharm's Python directory via:

```
# single package
$ pip install --no-index --find-links="<path>/tranferred_packages" <package>

# list of dependencies
$ pip install --no-index --find-links="<path>/tranferred_packages" -r requirements.txt
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Note- syntax has changed from "install --download" to download. Also, I have a question. When I run the command to download from a requirements file, I get this error: "Directory 'C:/.../newdirectory' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found."

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the second most voted answer on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation) you'll see the general way of doing it. You can do that with your `virtualenv` activated, then the packages *should* show up in PyCharm just fine

Answer (score 0):

On a computer that has an internet connexion download your packages with :

```
pip download -d <download folder directory> <package name>
```

Then on the target computer copy the download folder then go to Pycharm's Terminal and install your packages with:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links <download folder directory> <package name>
```