# How to install docker-compose offline?

Tags: linux, docker, installation, docker-compose

I would like to download docker-compose on one machine and install it on another (this other machine is not connected to the internet).

I tried downloading the binary file, making a docker-compose directory under `/usr/bin` (where docker is) and ran `chmod +x` on the directory. That didnt help.

Also the *Alternative Install Options* link in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#alternative-install-options) is broken :/

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-using-pip), you can install docker-compose with pip:

> Compose can be installed from pypi using pip. If you install using pip, we recommend that you use a virtualenv because many operating systems have python system packages that conflict with docker-compose dependencies.

And pip packages can be installed offline : [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Answer (score 18):

In situations when installing via pip or as docker container (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) is also not an option, the following option can help:

**Download the package in a system with connectivity (replace the needed version as required)**

```
wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64
```

**Just rename the package**

```
mv docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 docker-compose
```

**Copy it (ssh) to the required system**

**To make it executable**

```
sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin/
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Refer the post for more details: http://muralitechblog.com/how-to-install-docker-compose-offline/

Comment: `mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin/` would probably require sudo as well.

Comment: http://muralitechblog.com/how-to-install-docker-compose-offline/

Answer (score 0):

From the docker github page [docker compose github releases](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o docker-compose && chmod +x docker-compose
```

This will fetch the file applicable to the OS that you run the command for.

To find the latest version follow this link [Latest Docker Compose Releases](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest)
If you need to retrieve a version for an offline OS, on that OS run the following commands to determine the version.  NOTE: This is for linux and macOS varieties only.

To determine the OS

```
uname -s
```

To determine the architecture:

```
uname -m
```