# Install python packages offline on server

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, installation-package

I want to install some packages on the server which does not access to internet. so I have to take packages and send them to the server. But I do not know how can I install them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download all the packages you need and send them to the server where you need to install them. It doesn't matter if they have `*whl` or `*tar.gz` extension. Then install them one by one using `pip`:

```
pip install path/to/package
```

or:

```
python -m pip install path/to/package
```

The second option is useful if you have multiple interpreters on the server (e.g. python2 and python3 or multiple versions of either of them). In such case replace `python` with the one you want to use, e.g:

```
python3 -m pip install path/to/package
```

If you have a lot of packages, you can list them in a requirement file as you would normally do when you have access to the internet. Then instead of putting the names of the packages into the file, put the paths to the packages (one path per line). When you have the file, install all packages by typing:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In the requirements file you can also mix between different types of the packages (`*whl` and `*tar.gz`). The only thing to take care about is to download the correct versions of the packages you need for the platform you have (64bit packages for 64bit platform etc.).

You can find more information regarding `pip install` in its [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage).

Comment: This doesn't work unless both servers are the same OS and architecture.

Comment: @deed02392 I'm not sure what 2 servers you are talking about. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I use a macbook. The server is CentOS.

Comment: Sure, I understood that you use 2 different operating systems but why is it a problem? If your server with CentOS doesn't have access to the internet then download the packages for CentOS from [pypi](https://pypi.org/), put them to some place where the server have access and use [requirement specifiers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) in your `requirements.txt` (using `sys_platform` probably will be enough. If not then use combination of multiple specifiers).

Comment: I know I can download them from the pypi website, I'm just letting others know if they try to use pip as shown in this answer, it won't work for them across OSs if for example they need a package which has platform specific dependencies.

Comment: All the snippets above suggest to use paths to the downloaded packages which of course should match the platform on which you want to use them. If the package has dependencies then you need do download correct dependencies as well (assuming that the server is offline). Writing a proper requirements file which handles multiple OS's wasn't really in the scope of the question and I mentioned above that you need to take care about the architecture. Please be more specific about the part of the answer which doesn't work or is misleading to you because I don't see it

Answer (score 1):

You can either download the packages from the website and run `python setup.py install`. Or you can run a `pip install` on a local dir, such as :

```
pip install path/to/tar/ball
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage

Comment: on local dir of the package?

Answer (score -1):

Download the [`wheel`](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) packages  from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . You may install the `.whl` packages by `pip install (package.whl)` , refer [installing wheels using pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels) for more.

Comment: It doesn't matter from where the package is downloaded. `pip install path/to/package` is enough for `*whl` and `*tar.gz` files

Comment: These wheels are for Windows only.

Answer (score -2):

Download the package from website and extract the tar ball.
run `python setup.py install`