# How to deploy python-ldap module to Mac computer without Internet access (standalone package)

Tags: python, macos, pip, openldap, macos-high-sierra

I'm using python-ldap module on Mac OS 10.13. I need to deploy my code along with the python-ldap module to one hundred Mac, without internet access. Is there a way to accomplish this by only moving files around? Every Mac OS are at the same version (brand new image).

I easily installed python-ldap on my Mac with pip. My code is working fine.

I copied my code to a 2nd Mac along with the folder "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" containing what looks like the ldap module. When executing this same code on the 2nd Mac, the python-ldap module is found, but I receive the exception "can't find pyasn1 module".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+installation

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to build wheels of python-ldap and its dependencies [pyasn1](https://pypi.org/project/pyasn1) and [pyasn1-modules](https://pypi.org/project/pyasn1-modules).

For each module:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Then you can distribute the wheel files and install those.

(Another option could be to use the [brew](https://brew.sh/) repos.)