# Offline installation of dependent python modules without PIP

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, offline, easy-install

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Python offline package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation) as the answer require 'pip' to be present. My premise is when 'pip' is not available.

My python script depends on this [Github library](https://github.com/sileht/python-jsonpath-rw-ext). I need to create a self-sufficient tarball that includes this dependency and I can extract and run on my Production server, that does **not have access to internet or pip**. However I have Python 2.6.6/Python 2.7

I have created a virtualenv on my local machine (which has internet) and installed above dependency using pip. pip downloaded the dependent libraries. I obtained the requirements.txt with

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now I downloaded these requirements using

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

Downloaded contents are

```
decorator-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
jsonpath-rw-1.4.0.tar.gz  
jsonpath_rw_ext-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
pbr-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I also created a setup.py with `install_requires` having all the contents of the requirements.txt (followed from this [Python offline package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation))

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="Resizing Automation Validation Script",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=['ply','pbr','six','decorator','jsonpath-rw','jsonpath-rw-ext'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6.6",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

I tried running following command to install these scripts (pip is not available)

```
python setup.py develop --always-unzip --allow-hosts=None --find-links=/path/to/download/dir
```

Note: The above command works on a freshly created virtualenv in local.

But it on server(without internet) it fails with error

```
running develop
running egg_info
creating Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info
writing requirements to Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/requires.txt
writing Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Resizing_Automation_Validation_Script.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /deployeruser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Resizing-Automation-Validation-Script.egg-link (link to .)
Adding Resizing-Automation-Validation-Script 1.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /deployeruser/tmp
Processing dependencies for Resizing-Automation-Validation-Script==1.0.0
Searching for jsonpath-rw-ext

Link to https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonpath-rw-ext/ ***BLOCKED*** by --allow-hosts

Couldn't find index page for 'jsonpath-rw-ext' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)

Link to https://pypi.python.org/simple/ ***BLOCKED*** by --allow-hosts

No local packages or download links found for jsonpath-rw-ext
```

With pip it works fine

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ -r requirements.txt
```

However, how do I make it work without pip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I have referred to [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation) in my question already. I followed what was mentioned in it. But it reuires 'pip'. My question asks when pip is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing without pip requires you to install from the tarball archive directly. So,

1. First, get all the tarball archives for the dependencies
2. Transfer the tarballs to the dependent machine
3. Extract all the tarballs to temp folder
4. install using 'python setup.py install --user'
5. Run the program :)

---

Details:

1. Generate a requirements.txt using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
2. Getting tarballs from your python environment

   - cd to your download folder
   - Run `pip download -r ../requirements.txt --no-binary :all:`. This downloads all requirements as tar.gz archive into current directory

     > Remember to download all the inner dependencies that are missing from target machine. I needed to also download [setuptools-0.6c9](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/bc/70a3d8213cda12eac84c770895c54521d0d19847b512cef54d6c83b0ddcb/setuptools-0.6c9.tar.gz) for Python 2.6.6
3. Transfer the download folder to the production machine(without internet and pip)
4. cd to download folder and run following command to install the dependency to the currently active python.

   install_tarball_python.sh [tar.gz-file]

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script: install_tarball_python
# takes the tar.gz dependency as arg
# creates a temp directory and extracts the archive in it.
# 'cd's into the extracted archive and runs 'python setup.py install'
# 'cd's back to the current directory and removes the temp containing the decompressed archive

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: install_tarball_python <package.tar.gz>"
    exit 1
fi
pushd . && mkdir temp && tar zxf $1 -C temp && cd temp && cd * && python setup.py install --user&& popd && rm -rf temp
```

5. Run your python script.