# pip install from locally copied repo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pip

I wish to install connexion for swagger on a Ubuntu server that DOES NOT have internet access.

I wish to run

```
pip install connexion[swagger-ui]
```

Can I somehow download this repro (via another machine that does have internet access) and install/copy it locally and then install it that way?

If so, how?

Comment: On a machine with internet access: `pip download connexion[swagger-ui] --dest some/dir`, on the machine without internet access: `pip install connexion[swagger-ui] --no-index --find-links some/dir`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+install