# pip requesting package future which is already installed

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pip

Although `future` is installed, pip is still trying to collect it. This is an offline machine so packages cannot be auto-fetched. Using `pip3` instead of `python3 -m pip` will give same result.

```
$ python3 -m pip install ~/future-0.17.1.tar.gz
Processing /home/vader/future-0.17.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: future
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for future ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/vader/.cache/pip/wheels/c5/09/3a/1433ca68e4b2b77cd517ad0ef03182174a8f2c5fd0a8a89b1f
Successfully built future
Installing collected packages: future
Successfully installed future-0.17.1
$ python3 -m pip install ~/ffmpeg-python-0.1.18.tar.gz
Processing /home/vader/ffmpeg-python-0.1.18.tar.gz
Collecting future (from ffmpeg-python==0.1.18)
  Retrying...NewConnectionError...Failed to establish a new connection
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: What is the output if you add the  `-v` argument?

Comment: It's very long. On 2nd line already appears "Collecting future".

Comment: `python3 -m pip list` to check the list of installed packages, `python3 -m pip show future` to check package's info

Comment: An ugly but working thing would be decompressing the package and adjusting requirements in setup.py (i.e. removing install_requires).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+installation

Comment: `pip install --no-index ~/ffmpeg-python-0.1.18.tar.gz`

Comment: 2nd answer by @h4z3 solved.

Comment: Hahah. Yeah, sometimes to just get things working by a workaround is better than to understand why it was broken and fix it "properly" (assuming it was only one case like that). Glad it helped!