# Inconsistent python module version

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I got inconsistent module version number of selenium.

I installed selenium 3.141.0 [offline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/6306190):

```
>pip download selenium==3.141.0
```

```
>pip install --no-index --find-links E:\pip-selenium\3.141.0 selenium
Collecting selenium
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from selenium)
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0
```

Yet I get 3.4.0 in `__version__` variable:

```
>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>> print selenium.__version__
3.4.0
```

If I run `pip list` it says the version is 3.141.0:

```
>pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
comtypes (1.1.4)
mysql-python (1.2.3)
pip (9.0.3)
pyodbc (4.0.23)
pywin32 (223)
pywinauto (0.6.4)
selenium (3.141.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.11.0)
urllib3 (1.25.3)
```

What's happening?

Comment: Do you have python3 as well! ? check pip3 list!  and pip --version

Comment: I don't have python3. pip version is 9.0.3

Comment: The only possibility I can think is that your downloaded package is wrong. Try to check it first.

Comment: I specified the version when `pip download`, still the same result.

Comment: Could you print `sys.executable`?

Comment: `c:\Python27\python.exe`

Comment: This could be a possible issue. As in your `pip` command it shows `c:\python27`. You see, one is uppercase and one is lowercase. Not sure if you have two python2.7 in your system or this is just a display issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197477/discussion-between-johan-and-sraw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because I have two versions of selenium installed. Check `sys.path` and look for duplicate packages in those directories.