# How do I export a python package that I developed in such a way that all dependencies are included for offline installation on another machine?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, setuptools, packaging

I've developed a Python script on MacOS and I need to deploy it to a CentOS Linux server. The problem is that server doesn't have any internet access. I can only send over files using `scp`.

I tried [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation) already, but it didn't work, I think it is because the dependencies it downloaded were somehow specifically for MacOS. This is just a hunch, but the file names had "macos" in them.

There isn't really any code I can show as it's a packaging issue, not the code itself. Even the `setup.py` works perfectly as long as I'm using it on a machine with internet.

The other problem I have is I don't have `pip3` for some reason. I tried reinstalling python3 with different ./configure arguments, but I still don't have it. I do have the latest version of `pip`, but it's only linked to python 2.7.

Comment: Try a full-blown container, such as a `whl` file.

Comment: You have 2 different questions packed into 1. I recommend to ask them separately.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest in your case is to install pip for python 3. 
Since the server does not have a connection you should deploy it using pip 3?

Answer (score 0):

For offline usage at a different platform you have to download dependencies for the target platform:

```
pip download --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version=35 --implementation=cp --abi=cp35m -r requirements.txt
```

Version 3.5 is only used here as an example.