# How to package all my library dependencies in wheel file?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have one custom library/package (say `my_utils`) which has some library dependencies such as `pandas`, `numpy`, `boto`, etc. I have created `wheel` (`my_utils.whl`) of the same but it doesn't include the dependencies I have mentioned above. So when I install `my_utils.whl`, it'll download dependencies online.

My requirement is to install `my_utils.whl` file on a server which doesn't have an internet connection. So I want to package all the dependencies along with `my_utils.whl` to create `final_my_utils.whl`.

On the server, where I want to upload this wheel file, has GUI and can install only wheel files using `pip3 install final_my_utils.whl`

Is there any way I can achieve this?

**EDIT: Appreciate all the answers. But as I mentioned, the server on which I want to install this package has only GUI and I cannot run any commands. Internally, it'll run `pip3 install some_wheel.whl` file. Hence I want single wheel file packaging all dependencies.**

Comment: "which doesn't have an internet connection": If I get this right, you will need to package all the dependencies in your distributable. I have only attempted that in the past with https://www.pyinstaller.org. I think you will need to build on the same exact clone of the box (os, python version, etc) if any of your deps are C/C++ based or they require system libs (like openssl)

Comment: You can also check out bazel (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html) and buck (https://buck.build/rule/python_library.html#content) as alternative build and packaging systems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: As I mentioned, the server on which I want to install this package has only GUI and I cannot run any commands. Internally, it'll run pip3 install some_wheel.whl file. Hence I want single wheel file packaging all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need to create a `wheelhouse` dir in your project and cd in.

```
mkdir wheelhouse
cd wheelhouse
```

Second, you should run for all packages you want.

**for example**: numpy and flask ...

```
pip wheel numpy flask
```

All your wheels go into the `wheelhouse` dir. Just zip the dir, then, unzip it on the target server and run below script:

```
import glob, pip
for path in glob.glob("c:/path/to/wheelhouse/*.whl"):
    pip.main(['install', path])
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. But as I mentioned, the server on which I want to install this package has only GUI and I cannot run any commands. Internally, it'll run pip3 install some_wheel.whl file. Hence I want single wheel file packaging all dependencies.

Comment: @Darshan did you find an answer yet?