# How can I move a local conda environment to a remote server that does not have access to the internet?

Tags: python, conda, environment, remote-server

I have a conda environment on my local machine that has built some `pip` and `conda` packages. I want this environment to be available at a remote machine that does not have access to internet.

One way is to freeze the environment into a `environment.yml` or `requirements.txt` and be able to re-build the environment but this would fail since, the remote machine does not have access to online `pip` and `conda` repositories.

The other way is if I can transfer the folder `anaconda3/envs/<env_name>` to the remote machine, it should have all packages available on the remote machine.

Comment: Check out [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/)

Comment: Thanks @Albo conda-pack worked.

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/), which is exactly designed for this usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem this is how I installed Conda

in your laptop
     wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh (take latest)

Now SCP

```
  scp -i private/privateKey Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh
  chmod +x Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh
 ./Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p anaconda2
 ~/anaconda2/bin/python --version
```

Offline installation of pip 
[Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)