# How to download pip module for linux using windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-module

I am trying to download some modules on my windows machine, transfer them to offline Linux server via FTP where Python 3 and pip are installed. Then install the modules there using pip.

```
pip download --platform linux_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --no-binary=:none:  pandas
```

gives the error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

I can download using the below command but it is the windows version

```
pip download pandas
```

Answer (score 13):

The platform `linux_x86_64` is now named [`manylinux1_x86_64`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/). So run

```
pip download --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --no-binary=:none: pandas
```

Comment: My issue with this one is dependencies. For instance when I try to download Paramiko, it tries to download pynacl>=1.0.1.  Although there is ***PyNaCl-1.3.0-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (759.9 kB)*** on the PyPi, it gives the error:  

```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko)```

Comment: I tried `pip3.4 download --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --no-binary=:none: paramiko` and `pip` downloaded `PyNaCl-1.3.0-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` for me. But failed at `pycparser`. This is because `pycparser` is only available as [source distribution](https://pypi.org/project/pycparser/2.19/#files) and the command line specifically forbids sdists. I don't think there is any way around it other than downloading packages on the target (native) platform. A virtual machine, a docker container, a WSL terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @phd! Works with pandas, how could I install the downloaded `.whl` file after this.

Comment: @pc_pyr https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758

Comment: When I try to install it says `pandas-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform` since it's a linux package on windows, is there a way to bypass this and install it @phd

Comment: @pc_pyr No, you must have platform-specific wheels. Linux wheels on Linux, intel32/amd64 on Windows.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way I could install linux package in windows @phd

Comment: @pc_pyr No. Binary wheels contain extensions compiled by platform-specific compilers from C/C++ and these extensions can only be used at their proper platforms.

Answer (score -5):

try using the code as

```
python3 -m pip download [package name]
```

Edit, if this not work:
then download the package from pypi org and then run terminal where the file is located and then type python3 -m pip install copy the name of that package including .whl and then paste that name just after 'python3 -m pip install' hope it will work

Comment: I cannot download directly on the server. It has no connection. All I have is my windows machine and FTP to Linux server.

Comment: then download the package from pypi org and then run terminal where the file is located and then type python3 -m pip install copy the name of that package including .whl and then paste that name just after 'python3 -m pip install' hope it will work