# Downloading a python library and installing it locally from the computer

Tags: python

Have a bit of an issue here.  I haven't got admin access to my work computer (working on getting it) so I can't install packages.  IT has given me a temporary Admin password but Admin doesn't have internet access.

So I have to download the library itself.  I went to 
https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn.git
and downloaded "imbalanced-learn-master.zip"

My question now is - how do I install this on my computer locally?  I can "Run as Administrator" anything from the command prompt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: Just a comment since this is not answering directly to your question but you can install `miniconda` and then you can manage it a user level (still require internet) without the admin rights. Then whatever package can be installed with `conda install <package-name>`.

Answer (score 1):

First. How You install packages. 
If from command line then you can use `--user` switch 
then command will look

```
pip install --user imbalanced-learn
```

Other option is to install from wheel file. So download: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/aa/eba717a14df36f0b6f000ebfaf24c3189cd7987130f66cc3513efead8c2a/imbalanced_learn-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl 
and then

```
pip install imbalanced_learn-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

or without admin privileges

```
pip install --user imbalanced_learn-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Third option is to install from source (as you asked). You need to unpack zip file and in terminal go to main folder (with `setup.py`) and then

```
pip install .
```

But you also need to install package dependencies. You can found them in `setup.py`
For current master it is

```py
INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    'numpy>=1.11',
    'scipy>=0.17',
    'scikit-learn>=0.22',
    'joblib>=0.11'
]
```

Comment: I've been trying the "pip install ." and this is what I see:  "Processing c:\temp\imbalanced-learn-master    Requirement already satisfied numpy, requirement already satisfied scipy, collecting scikit-learn".  Then it tries to connect to the internet and under admin there is no internet.  So is my problem, I have an outdated scikit-learn and need to update that library prior to the imbalanced library?

Comment: Or you may not have installed it. Yo may download it from https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#files

Comment: just checked using "pip list" and returns skikit-learn 0.21.2

Comment: So version is to low.

Comment: Yes, you need to get scikit-learn 0.22. It is available on PyPI and conda-forge.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to locally install scikit-learn 0.22.  "Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error    ERROR:  Complete output from command 'C:\Users\jhalfyard\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JHALFY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-986aaels\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\JHALFY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1lx202se' --py

Comment: ERROR: Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Comment: download proper wheel files from this webpage:  https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#files
I thintk that it will be somenting like `scikit_learn-0.22-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` where cp36 means python 3.6 and you need to check whic version of python you use. 

If you ask such question do not try to build python package from source if wheel (*.whl) file is available.

Comment: So I have a windows machine, and a 64-bit computer so I imagine i'd use the link but this link is not functioning https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/10/1dd2e3436e13402cc2b16c61b5f7407fb2e8057dcc18461db0d8e3523202/scikit_learn-0.22-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: The file is available and I am able to download the file.

Comment: Talk with your administrator to check network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the pip (or any package installer) through your corporate proxy.

```
pip install package_name --proxy=http://corporate-proxy.company_website.com:8080
```