# upgrade python package from wheel file using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use a wheel file to upgrade some python packages through pip.
I have installed pandas 19.2 for my python, and I also have `.whl` file for pandas 23.0. I would like to upgrade pandas from 19.2 to 23.0. I searched online. I could only see people using pip install with a wheel file.
Is it possible to upgrade from the wheel file? Will `pip install mypandas.whl` create any problems? How about its dependencies? Will pip `install --upgrade` allow to take `*.whl` as its input?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758