# Install requests offline and without pip

Tags: python, module, pip

I have a machine where Python 3.1 is installed. I want to install module "`requests`", but I have no `pip` and the machine is offline (no `setuptools` nor `distribute`). What should I do ?

Is it possible to install the module in my case ?

Comment: Get a new machine, or at least update Python. The last version of requests supporting Python 3.1 is 7 years old. And Python 3.1 is even older.

Comment: Are you sure it's Python 3.1? That's over 10 years old. And the current version of `requests` supports a Python version >= 3.5.

Comment: Yes I am sure, and it's on Windows 2008, now I need a solution ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab a copy of requests from the repo: 
https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/README.md

```
git clone git://github.com/psf/requests.git
```

As noted in the comments requests only supports 2.7 and 3.5+ you can try hacking it up but, this is the supported method by the developers of the module.

I can safely tell you that the version you are looking for is between 0.2.4 (2011-02-19) which is when 2.5 support was added and 0.14.1 (2012-10-01) when 3.3 support was added.

There is a side note that 2.5 support was dropped on 0.10.1 (2012-01-23) and python 3 support was added. I started at 1.0.0 and worked my way through the change log. https://pypi.org/project/requests/1.0.0/#description

In all likelihood you are looking at 0.10.1 - 0.14.1 for the exact package. From there just download and install with the setup.py as per usual.

Comment: Latest version I could find for Python 3.1 is 1.1.0: https://pypi.org/project/requests/1.1.0/#files -- https://github.com/psf/requests/tree/v1.1.0