# How to use pip install while activating virtual environment in python

Tags: python, centos7

I've installed a separated python version and activated virtual environment based on it ,  on `CentOs7` when i use the `pip install` method from offline packages i got this error  :

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 127:
     command: /home/awagdy/Documents/reporter-web/venv/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jlfbivgb/Django/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jlfbivgb/Django/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jlfbivgb/Django/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    /home/awagdy/Documents/reporter-web/venv/bin/python3.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 127: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm installing from a folder that contains the needed packages downloaded using the command `pip download` , then installing them offline using `pip install -r requirements.txt --no--index --find-links=pkgs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this command helped `path/to/python/python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links=path/to/pkgs`

Answer (score 0):

The link below, the person suggests using 
`easy_install` when installing python packages in a virtual environment

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)