# Install python modules offline

Tags: python, pip

I am working on an offline platform (no direct access to the internet).
And need to install many python modules.
So I download them manually, copy them to the server and then install using `#pip install <package_path>`.
It is very difficult and time consuming...is there a way to download/create an offline repository or create a mirror in my environment??
best way of installing the python modules please.

Comment: Which type of access do you have on that platform ? You can think to make a virtualenv, create a tarball and then copy to the target host.

Comment: What do you mean by no direct access the internet, and how is the platform your using connected to the server without an internet connection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758

Comment: From where you have installed the packages, in the command prompt
pip freeze > req.txt
A new file req.txt will be generated 
In the same command prompt type pip download -d wheel_packages -r req.txt 
(Ignore the -d wheel_packages, if you want it to download in the same folder) 

copy this wheel_packages folder in server where there is no internet and in cmd type dir /s /b "path_to_wheel_packages" > offline_req.txt 
A file named offine_req.txt will be generated. 

pip install --no-cache-dir -r offline_req.txt