# How to download repository Python (pip) for an offline station

Tags: python, download, repository

Today I have a problem to develop in my company on a dev-station outside the network (for security).

I have to download the packages one by one. Because the web station does not have python (I'm not an admin). So I want to download (on my home) a repository on a hard drive and connect it to my development station (after scan virus of course :) ).

Can you help me?

Do you known some commands to do that on linux OS?

Best regards. Thanks x 10000 for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [link](http://thelazylog.com/install-python-as-local-user-on-linux/) on installing python and pip as user (without root permission). Then follow the steps below to use pip to get the repo files.

The pip command itself has a download option that you can use to download the package. It also downloads the dependent (requirements) packages.

```
pip download --no-cache-dir package_names
```

Here package_names are required packages separated by space. Either you can run in single command or run multiple command for multiple packages according to your need.
For example:

```
$ mkdir repo && cd repo
$ pip download openpyxl psutil
Collecting openpyxl
  Downloading openpyxl-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 241 kB 1.6 MB/s 
  Saved ./openpyxl-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psutil
  Downloading psutil-5.7.2.tar.gz (460 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 460 kB 5.1 MB/s 
  Saved ./psutil-5.7.2.tar.gz
Collecting jdcal
  Downloading jdcal-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
  Saved ./jdcal-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting et-xmlfile
  Downloading et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz (8.4 kB)
  Saved ./et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz
Successfully downloaded openpyxl psutil jdcal et-xmlfile
```

Then on the developer machine just install using pip install

```
$ cd reop
$ pip install *
```

Note: if you have requirements.txt, you could download as

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/

You can just use `pip download`, provide the directory with `-d` and then use pip install later

```
$ pip download -d /tmp/package SomePackage
```