# Download packages from Pypi with a script

Tags: python, download, pip, package, pypi

Is there a programmatical way to download necessary package .tar.gz files from pypi.

The point is, we need to use a server that has no access to the internet and pypi. That is why i wanted to automate the download of all packages and dependant packages used in a script, so we can download and transfer them all together and install them there locally.

Any ideas welcome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758