# Installing Python packages without using pip or conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to run a .py script in a remote desktop. I'm trying to import the different modules I need to run the script but I'm unable to as I don't have pip or Anaconda. I've tried installing pip by running the `get-pip.py` file but I'm getting the following error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip`

I've also tried running it using the ensurepip method but the error I then get is:

`unable to import setuptools`

The only workaround for this is to install that module using `pip`, which I do not have.

I then tried using Conda but I'm unable to install Anaconda due to admin rights to the remote server I'm using.

I also tried installing Jupyter notebook but again, wasn't able to due to admin rights.

I've been able to do this no problem in my local machine but not in this remote desktop. I'm also unable to get further admin rights.

Is there another option to get Python modules without using `pip` or `conda`?

Comment: Python version is 3.9.7 and I'm using Windows Server 2012 64-bit. Turns out I can't download pip since I don't have internet access on the remote server.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments but [edit] your question. Note that this information makes your question completely different!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)

Comment: See also [Download & Install pip packages offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968055/) or [How to pip install with no network access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385935/)

Answer (score -1):

1. Try finding the supported rpms for your python code specific to your OS(RHEL/CENTOS/FEDORA/UBUNTU)

for example:
If you are using flask in python2 script then try python2 flask rpm module to install in your OS.
Similarly, for python3.

As a workaround, you can also create your own custom module whichever you are importing to your application.