# Installing python module from zip using pip fails

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install this module https://github.com/consbio/tpkutils on my windows server 2012, by using pip on my virtual machine, it does not have internet connectivity so I've tried installing from zip. I don't have experience with python, that's why I need Your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89kam.png)

```
pip install zipname.zip
```

Comment: The module you are trying to install, has dependencies to other modules (they can have dependencies as well) which are automatically fetched from the internet by pip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758