# Does Python pip work in offline environments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, package

I am currently using an offline Windows 10 environment and I need to use pip to install a package.

The traditional **pip install "myPackage.tar.gz"**  is not working because pip makes a network request and fails because my machine has no internet.

With this in  mind I tried the following command to ignore dependency checking. **pip install myPackage.tar.gz  -f./ --no-index –-no-deps**. The command did install “Successfully ” but when I tried to use the package I got a ModuleNotFoundError.

My question is does pip work offline? If  not what would be a work around?

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: There are a few questions like this with some good answers. Just search "pip offline install tar.gz"

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758

Answer (score 1):

Do you have those packages already downloaded in your computer?
If not, at some point you will need an internet connection.

There's `pip download` command which lets you download packages without installing them:

`pip download -r requirements.txt`

(In previous versions of pip, this was spelled pip install --download -r requirements.txt.)

When you have your packages downloaded, use `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ -r requirements.txt` to install what you have previously downloaded, without the need to access on internet

Comment: Please, set it as accepted answer if it solved your question!