# How to forward the library downloaded with pip?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have two linux servers, one can be connected to the Internet, and the other can't. I downloaded some libraries using `pip install library` on a server that can be connected to the Internet, and I want to transfer it to another server. But how to set install paths? And how do I know which files are installed by pip?  Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Esp. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize `wheel` in this case, which can make packages that you can bring to your offline machine. For example with `numpy`

```
pip wheel numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.20.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (13.6 MB)
Saved c:\numpy-1.20.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Then on your other machine copy these wheels and use pip

```
pip install numpy-1.20.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

You can do a similar thing with `requirements.txt` to gather a number of wheels at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to install the modules in a virtual environment, e.g. `python3 -m venv .venv` followed by your `pip install <module>` and then copy the entire `.venv` directory to the remote machine.

Cory Kramer suggests using wheels which a good alternative option too. Either method should work.