# How to convert dist-packages / site-packages to pip repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, pypiserver

On enterprise systems where no internet might be some computer with relevant python packages,

Is it possible to convert dist-packages / site-packages to private repository.

In Java i able to upload jar to Artifactory/Nexus and it will work when i add dependency. Is it same case from site-packages/dist-packages ?

Comment: No, there're not enough code in `site-packages` to convert installed packages back into distributions. You need to download distribution packages on a connected host; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Offtopic: your certificate for the host `alefbt.com` has just expired. Please update.

Comment: you could try to copy folder to new place - maybe it will work. But if package uses C/C++ code compiled for different CPU then using this module is useless.