# How to pip install with no network access?

Tags: python, pip

I'm working on packaging a Python project into a Flatpak and one of the tough parts of the process is that you need to specify everything that'll be downloaded *in advance* of the build because the builder will fetch only those files and then start the build *without any network access*.

This was simple enough: I wrote a script to spider through my dependencies and generate a list of packages to download in advance, and the builder now just happily goes through the list doing `pip3 install --prefix=/app --no-deps .` for each `.tar.gz` file there.

However, the build fails because even though `--no-deps` is specified, it's still trying to access the network to resolve dependencies.  Here's the output from traitlets for example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test-stuff
$ cd /tmp/test-stuff
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/24/e6dfe45ecfc4c2b0d6774565e631dc1b9e50de2c3536625d377963d56cae/traitlets-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf traitlets-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd traitlets-5.0.5

[disable my network connection]

$ pip3 install --prefix=/app --no-deps .

Processing /tmp/test-stuff/traitlets-5.0.5
  DEPRECATION: A future pip version will change local packages to be built in-place without first copying to a temporary directory. We recommend you use --use-feature=in-tree-build to test your packages with this new behavior before it becomes the default.
   pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7555.
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /tmp/test-stuff/.venv/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-fi7402mr/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-t15e0kws/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4a69b37490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4a698dbcd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4a698db040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4a698db280>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4a698db490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/setuptools/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///tmp/test-stuff/traitlets-5.0.5. Command errored out with exit status 1: /tmp/test-stuff/.venv/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-fi7402mr/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-t15e0kws/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /tmp/test-stuff/.venv/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-fi7402mr/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-t15e0kws/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

So my question is: how can I get pip to install something without trying to fetch dependencies, since `--no-deps` doesn't appear to be doing that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Esp. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 : `pip install --no-index`