# How to manually install python package waitress on a server without internet connection?

Tags: python, linux, pip

Since the server is not able to connect the internet, so I can not just do
`pip install waitress` simply.

And I try to download and unzip the package from github(https://github.com/Pylons/waitress), and try `pip install .` or `conda install *`, but here is the error report.

```
(base) [root@localhost waitress-2.0.0]# pip install .
Processing /usr/local/python3/waitress-2.0.0
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /root/anaconda3/bin/python /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-5_heyly2/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 41'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6b89219460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 未知的名称或服务')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6b89219670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 未知的名称或服务')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6b89219850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 未知的名称或服务')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6b89219a30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 未知的名称或服务')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6b89219c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 未知的名称或服务')': /simple/setuptools/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=41
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=41
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///usr/local/python3/waitress-2.0.0. Command errored out with exit status 1: /root/anaconda3/bin/python /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-5_heyly2/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 41' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /root/anaconda3/bin/python /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-5_heyly2/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 41' Check the logs for full command output.
(base) [root@localhost waitress-2.0.0]#
```

How can I successfully install the package waitress?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758