# install boto3 on an offline RHEL server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to install boto3 on rhel 7 server.
I have pip3 installed, all the other things needed for boto3.

```
yum list installed | grep -i python3
```

I have python3.x86_64, python3-libs.x86_64, python3-pip.noarch and python3-setuptools.noarch

```
whereis python3
```

As internet connection is not setup, I am getting an error with respect to accessing

```
pip install boto3   #does not work due to external connection problem.
```

Got latest code from boto3 https://github.com/boto/boto3.git
has issues with dependencies from it.

Does anyone know of any links which might help with list of steps to follow to install boto3 when server is not connected to internet

thanks
Dan

Comment: Normally, you would create your own AMI for that. The AMI is created when the development instance is connected to the internet. Then you just create private instance using the AMI without any internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like raLdza pointed out
[How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)

Here are the steps:

> **On the system that has access to internet**
> The pip download command lets you download packages without installing them:

> ```
> pip download -r requirements.txt
> ```

> (In previous versions of pip, this was spelled `pip install --download -r requirements.txt`.)

> **On the system that has no access to internet**
> Then you can use

> ```
> pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ -r requirements.txt
> ```
>
> to install those downloaded modules, without accessing the network.