# LDAP installation for Python without Pip and .org's

Tags: python, pip, ldap

i want to use LDAP with python and dont have the opportunity to use pip with pypi.python.org, pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org. (cant get through Proxy, wont change)

so i need to download the package and install it.
as i understand there are .whl and zipped packages.

1. i tried bonsai but got the error C1083 because of the missing file basetsd.h
2. i tried python_ldap but it called for pyasn1, so i tried to install pyasn1 but it gave me a 407 Proxy Authorization Required -- Some packages may not be found Line with Error "Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6')
   There where no red or yellow errors so i tried python_ldap again, but with the same error like on the first attempt.

how do i setup a LDAP for Python if i cant reach pypi.python.org, pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org  ?

Greetings
Chorum

- Python: 3.10.1
- Pip: 21.2.4

Comment: What prevented you from downloading the appropriate whl file for `pyasn1` and then installing that? https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: mhmm i used the wrong *.whl .... -> pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any the 0.4.8 worked ! thx! i could install python_ldap too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11091623/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline