# How can i install pygame on my internet not connected computer?

Tags: python, installation, pygame, offline

i'm trying to install pygame package on my computer which one is not connected to internet.

(env : windows10, python 3.9(anaconda))

so i downloaded a "pygame-2.1.2.tar" file from [www.pypi.org](http://www.pypi.org) and then tried to install it

from cmd with "python setup.py install" commend.

then it shows error message like below

```
    ===============================================================================

    (base) C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2>python setup.py install
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip        
    d561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in         
    _new_conn
        conn = connection.create_connection(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73,         
    in create_connection
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699,         
    in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, 
    in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010,         
    in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in 
    connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in 
    _new_conn
        raise NewConnectionError(
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 
    0x00000237AF075250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo 
    failed

    

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in 
    send
        resp = conn.urlopen(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, 
    in urlopen
        retries = retries.increment(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in         
    increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.libsdl.org', port=443):         
    Max retries exceeded with url: /release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip (Caused by 
    NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000237AF075250>: 
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 497, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 290, in         
    ask
        update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 273, in 
    update
        download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 124, in                         
    download_prebuilts
        download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
      File "C:\pythonpackage\pygame-2.1.2\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 47, in         
    download_sha1_unzip
        response = requests.get(url)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
        return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in 
    request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in         
    send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in 
    send
        raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.libsdl.org', port=443):         
    Max retries exceeded with url: /release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip (Caused by 
    NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000237AF075250>: 
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
    
    ===============================================================================
```

please let me know how to install pygame on offline environment.

i need your help!! please~~

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)

Comment: unfortunately it's not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 (It works for me; simple but tricky)

My first suggestion is just using `.whl` file. You can download `pygame.whl`, which is another type of installation file, from another computer and move the two files to the computer with no internect connection.

You can download the files here:

- `.whl` file for Window & Python3.9 (for example,
  pygame-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl):
  https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files

Actually, `.whl` is a zipfile. You can unzip the `.whl` file then you can see three folders: pygame, pygame-2.1.2.data, and pygame-2.1.2.dist-info. You just need `pygame` folder.

You can copy the folder and paste it to your python project. Then you can simply `import pygame`. I just tried this way and it works for me. (I even tried to run an example game)

## Solution 2

Another suggestion is to download `pip` and `pygame.whl` from another computer and move the two files to the computer with no internect connection.

You can download the files here:

- pip (for example, pip-22.0.3.tar.gz): https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files
- `.whl` file for Window & Python3.9 (for example,
  pygame-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl):
  https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files

After downloading and moving the two files to the computer with no internect connection, you first unzip the `pip-22.0.3.tar.gz` and install pip by tying following command inside of the pip folder (pip also has `setup.py` file):

```
python setup.py install
```

Now, `pip` has been installed. Then, install using the `.whl` file using pip in the folder that `.whl` file exist.

```
python -m pip install pygame-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

I hope it help you emjoy `pygame`.

Comment: i tried but an error occured again.
i put command : python -m pip install pygame-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
and the error was "pygame-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform" how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @강승호 Are you using 32bits? Then, you have to download 32 bits version of file `pygame-2.1.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl`.

Comment: @ it's 64 bit!!

Comment: @강승호 Try first solution. There is no needs to run any commands. just download it and unzip the `.whl` fie, and move it to your python projeect folder so that you can import it.

Comment: @강승호 Then, try first solution without using pip. It just confirm that it works.

Comment: first solution works! Thank you!

Comment: @강승호 So happy to hear that :) Than, plz accept my answer so that others can refer it when they face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can run command: pip install pygame

Comment: well, the machine that i want to install pygame is not connected to internet.
so pip install is not work!