# Moving Python venv to another machine without internet

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, environment

I am trying to deploy a Python project to a machine with no internet.  Because it has no internet, I cannot pip install any packages with a `requirements.txt` file.  I am wondering if it is possible to move my existing environment with all installed packages into another machine with all packages pre-installed.

I can also use attempt to use Docker for this installation.  Would I be able to pre-install all the packages within a Docker container and then copy all the files onto another VM?

Comment: yes, in most cases virtual environments can be simply copied same is also true for Docker images. It won't work if the hardware problem is different, packages include compiled libraries, and kernel/libs are substantially different across targets.

Comment: Do you have pip on the remote machine?

Comment: I can probably install pip on the remote machine, but it would not have it natively.  The remote machine will be a VM running Windows Server 2016.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On you local machine (adapt the instructions if you are on Windows)

1. Create your `requirements.txt` file

```
(venv) [...]$ mkdir pkgs
(venv) [...]$ cd pkgs
(venv) [...]$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
(venv) [...]$ pip download -r requirements.txt
```

2. Download `pip` archive from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files)
3. Copy `pkgs` folder to the remote machine

On the remote machine:

4. Install `pip` from archive

```
(venv) [...]$ cd pkgs
# --- unarchive pip.tar.gz ---
(venv) [...]$ python setup.py install
```

5. Install packages

```
(venv) [...]$ pip install --no-index --find-links . -r requirements.txt
```