# installing pip offline got error "no module named 'setuptools' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Hi I've been trying to install python and all of my depedencies with "offline mode".
i've downloaded manually from the machine that has internet.

I installed python v3.10
Now I'm trying to install pip-22.2.2, but i got an error that says :

```
ModuleNotFoundError :No module named 'setuptools'
```

My command is :

```
python setup.py install
```

My directory is  :
Python : .../.../Python/Python310

Pip : .../.../Python/Python310/pip-22.2.2

I'm on windows 10

Comment: Download and install [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files) package first?

Comment: ah yeah sorry, it's solved now, i thought python already has that from its installation..
btw thanks for the responds

Comment: yw. For your information if you want to create an offline environment, I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461335/15239951) about this. Setuptools is automatically downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error that says "No module named 'setuptools'", it means that you are missing the setuptools module, which is required for the installation of pip. You can download the setuptools module from https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files. After downloading, you can install the module by running the command python setup.py install