# How to get .whl file, if a library is already installed?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a python library installed on my pc. I did it with pip install. Is it possible to create .whl file of that library with Python code?
I need it, because i don't have access to internet on that pc currently.

Comment: It should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460911/moving-python-venv-to-another-machine-without-internet/71461335#71461335

Comment: @Corralien this solution is not suitable. there is a step Download library archive from  pipy. but i cannot do it, my pc doesn't have access to internet. if i could go to pypi web page, i would download .whl file from there

Comment: Maybe some variant of [`python -m pip wheel --no-index --no-deps NameOfLibrary`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/). Otherwise maybe the wheel is already in one of *pip*'s caches (build cache or download cache).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try some variant of [`python -m pip wheel --no-index --no-deps NameOfLibrary`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/).

Otherwise maybe the wheel is already in one of *pip*'s caches (build cache or download cache). You can find their location with [`python -m pip cache info`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_cache/) and go from there.