# How to run tox without internet connection?

Tags: python, tox

When I try to run tox without an internet connection it prints the following error message:

```
py3 inst-nodeps: mypackage/.tox/.tmp/package/1/mypackage-0.1.1.dev0.tar.gz
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: mypackage/.tox/py3/log/py3-12.log
=================================================================================== log start ===================================================================================
Processing ./.tox/.tmp/package/1/mypackage-0.1.1.dev0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbb577c1dc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flit-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbb577c1e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flit-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbb577c1b20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flit-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbb577c1760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flit-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbb5783fc10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/flit-core/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flit_core<4,>=3.2 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for flit_core<4,>=3.2
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

==================================================================================== log end ====================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________ summary ____________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py3: InvocationError for command mypackage/.tox/py3/bin/python -m pip install --no-deps -U .tox/.tmp/package/1/mypackage-0.1.1.dev0.tar.gz (exited with code 1)
```

My tox.ini looks like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = py3
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
deps =
    mypy
    pytest
    types-appdirs
commands =
    mypy src/mypackage tests
    pytest
```

Running tox with an internet connection works as expected.

I have tried the advice given in [this issue](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1151) of adding the following lines to my tox.ini but seemingly without any effect, I cannot run tox without an internet connection.

```
setenv = VIRTUALENV_DOWNLOAD=0
         PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1
```

I am using tox 3.25.0 and pip 20.3.4 and I have tried this in two different projects, one using flit 3.7.1 and one using setuptools.

Does anyone have an idea how I can run tox without an internet connection?

Comment: "*I cannot run tox without an internet connection.*" What is the problem? Error message? Dependencies?

Comment: @phd thank you for your comment. I'm sorry I forgot to add the error message. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [pre-download dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758) and install them offline. In tox.ini use [`install_command`](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command). Something like

```
[testenv]
install_command=python -m pip install {opts} --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ {packages}
```