# Merge third party package into python whl file

Tags: pip

I need to make a .whl file of a package and it will be installed in a isolated environment which cannot connect to Internet.

In this package, it will use some third party libraries for example black and pydantic. I know that in setup.py we can set "required" packages, but this method will work only if the environment can connect to Internet.

Currently I use a workaround. This is my directory structure.

```
└── src
    └── my_package
```

I download the required packages and add them to my source code before packing them into a whl file.

```
pip install --target=lib -r requirements.txt
cp -r lib/* src
```

So the directory structure will be like below

```
└── src
    ├── my_package
    ├── black
    └── pydantic
```

In my setup.py, I set

```
package_dir={
        "": "src",
    },
```

So that after I pip install this whl file, my_package, black, pydantic will appear in python **site-packages** directory.

However, with this method, console script of third party libraries like `black test.py` cannot work since there is no console script under the **(virtualenv path)/bin** directory.
Is there a more elegant way to merge third party libraries into my whl file?

Regards,

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Instead, why not download all the wheels you need (including black, pydantic, etc.) in advance and transfer them to the target machine? This is called building a "wheelhouse", it is a common practice.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since I don't know how others usually do to deal with this problem, this is the only approach I came up with. I will try with the wheelhouse approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: @phd Yes. Thank you. I think "pip download" or "pip wheels" may solve my problem.