# How to reference Python libraries in local folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, r, rstudio

Is it possible in a Python script to reference a folder where the libraries are located? Example: pandas, plotly, numpy, etc.

In my work there is a network block that does not allow the installation of external libraries, so I downloaded the libraries on my computer at home and brought it to work thinking that there is some way to reference the imports of my libraries through this folder as done in RStudio with .libPath. If possible, how could do this?

Image in the Folder libraries:

[image]

Comment: You need to download the wheel of tar.gz format of the libraries, then do `pip install pandas.whl`,

Comment: But in this case, as I don't have access to installing external libraries, it is not possible to do this because I need to update the pip version, but for that it would have to be with libraries in a folder, I believe

Comment: I think this topic can helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sys.path from the sys library in python.

You can download the library and add the path in the python script:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/path_to/downloaded_librarie")

import downloaded_librarie
```

Comment: in this way? https://imgur.com/pKgh5xA

Comment: Try, "C:/repo" instead of "C:\repo".

Comment: it still doesn't work, does my folder with the libraries does it have to be like this as shown on the print?? "whl"?

Answer (score -1):

1. On a computer with internet do `pip download pip pandas numpy plotly`
2. You have one file per packages, and its dependencies
3. Copy the files on the non-internet computer
4. Run `pip install *` `*` being **only** all the files you downloaded

Comment: in this way?
pip install \\sad154000\Corporativo\Gepej\#NOVA_ESTRUTURA\Estagiarios\PythonLibrary                             


OBS: this is the path where there is a folder of all libraries inside the "Python Library"

Comment: @Deforceh doesn't matter where the files are, just do `pip install pandas...whl` Also read about virtualenv to avoi setting glogal packages https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: I added image in the question to see the libraries that I saved in folder, for this path above. Note: if I give the command: pip install ** pandas.whl it gives the following warning: [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: @Deforceh we don't care about the warning, we don't need the latest pip version. Also please use english here

Comment: but after running the command "pip install **pandas.whl" it does nothing but this pip update warning

Comment: @Deforceh You need to use the file names given by the download, regarding you screenshot it may be `pip install pandas.rar`, look again my post : download the files, call "pip install" on them

Comment: but the pandas.rar file is in a folder with different paths, so would need to tell the code where this library is, wouldn't you? OBS: I already use venv as a virtual environment to install these libraries

Comment: @Deforceh pip install it somewhere, THEN python know where it is, because pip installed it

Comment: @azo imgur.com/pKgh5xA