# Numpy error while trying to install on offline server: OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as module

Tags: python, numpy, cython, setup.py

I need to install some python libraries on a offline server but I got stuck trying.

I decided to start with a basic library like Numpy first. But I can't make it work because I'm getting errors:

1. Downloading numpy-1.24.2.tar.gz from pypi.org, extracting the folder and run `python setup.py install`

[cython needs to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRHBS.png)

1. Copying numpy folder from an online computer from the path: `C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages` and trying the same line command `python setup.py install`

[wrong setup.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Xrm.png)

Also tried to install cython but it requires VS BuildTools which also requires internet connection to be installed

How Can I install numpy and any other python libraries if the server doesn't have internet access?

Comment: Pypi probably contains some "whl" files of precompiled Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Followed this tread to download pip installation packages from my online server to the offline and worked

[How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline)