# How to migrate python packages from one environment to other environment which dont have internet connectivity and also pip installed

Tags: python, pip, offline, python-packaging, python-wheel

I have two VMs one is development VM and one is Production VM. Development VM has internet access but production VM dont have it and will not get access.

I want some python packages to be installed to run some script. In development VM I installed    those packages. Script is running file. I want to migrate this packages to production VM. Where pip is not installed as well as internet is also not there.

I am looking for a way i can zip the packages migrate it to prod VM using scp and install over there.

I can not directly zip python2.7/site-packages where packages are being installed by pip because there are many unnecessary packages present in development VM. I want only those which are required for script to run with all its dependency.

I tried downloading source tar.gz from https://pypi.org/ and install it through "setup.py install" but it requires so much dependency issues.

I am looking for solution like i create directory all the packages will be installed in that directories with all the dependencies. And i can zip it and put it in other setup.

Also a way so that it doesnt upgrade any of the packages preinstalled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Answer (score 1):

Build a "[*wheelhouse*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles)" on the machine that has internet connection. Something like the following, check *pip*'s documentation for exact command and details.

First, in the environment you want to mirror, get the list of dependencies:

```
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Maybe, edit the `requirements.txt` file to remove dependencies that you do not want or need. It might be more or less complex to figure out what dependencies should be kept in the `requirements.txt` file or not. You can use tools like [*deptree*](https://pypi.org/project/deptree/), [*pipdeptree*](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/), [*creosote*](https://pypi.org/project/creosote/), [*pipreqs*](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/), or [*pigar*](https://pypi.org/project/pigar/).

Then build the actual *wheelhouse*, you might want to do this in a fresh empty virtual environment, if you are worried about making modifications in your source environment:

```
python -m pip wheel --requirement requirements.txt --wheel-dir=wheelhouse/
```

The `wheelhouse` directory can be copied over to the target machine.

And the dependencies can be installed in the target environment with *pip* without internet connection:

```
python -m pip install --no-index wheelhouse/*.whl
```

---

If the target machine, really does not have *pip* (which seems quite unlikely), you could use a [*zipapp*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html)-based solution such as [*pex*](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) or [*shiv*](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/).