# Requirements disparities between pip show and Pypi API

Tags: python, scripting, pypi

I am building a script to download python libs for later deployement on a offline machine.
I considered using either the **Pypi API** or **cli pip show** to get the dependencies of libs to install.

My issue is that the "requires_dist" object from the JSON provided by the API lists more dependencies  than what is listed in the "Requires: " field of pip show.
Which is the correct list of requirements ?

Here's an example with the django lib:

**Through pip:** `py -m pip show django`

```
Name: Django
Version: 4.0.4
Summary: A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: d:\boyan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: sqlparse, tzdata, asgiref
Required-by:
```

**Through the API:** https://pypi.org/pypi/django/json

```
...
    "release_url": "https://pypi.org/project/Django/4.2/",
    "requires_dist": [
      "asgiref (<4,>=3.6.0)",
      "sqlparse (>=0.3.1)",
      "backports.zoneinfo ; python_version < \"3.9\"",
      "tzdata ; sys_platform == \"win32\"",
      "argon2-cffi (>=19.1.0) ; extra == 'argon2'",
      "bcrypt ; extra == 'bcrypt'"
    ],
    "requires_python": ">=3.8",
...
```

I tried to install manually several libs, and empirically the pip approach seeems correct. That said, is it a good practice to directly parse a cmd output ? I know Pypi tend to change those occasionally.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use `pip download` to download all recursive dependencies. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the output and what you get, you need to consider constraints shown in the API output:

```
"backports.zoneinfo ; python_version < \"3.9\"",
```

I'll assume you have a later version of python so this is skipped. Next is:

```
"argon2-cffi (>=19.1.0) ; extra == 'argon2'",
"bcrypt ; extra == 'bcrypt'"
```

These are extra dependencies, which means they won't be installed unless you explicitly ask for them during install. Unfortunately [due to a bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3797) they won't show even if you installed all the extras such as `pip install django[bcrypt,argon2]`.