# Unable to install jax 0.4.12 python package in an offline environment in Python 3.11.3 in RHEL 7.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, jax

When installing jax package offline it is failing and looking for setuptools package. However I already have setuptools installed. setuptools               60.0.0

I also tried the latest version of setuptools which is 67 but same issue is there.

This is the error message:

[root@lorenz Python-3.11.3]# ./python -m pip install --no-index /mnt/python/jax/*
Processing /mnt/python/jax/jax-0.4.12.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [2 lines of output]
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

But if I tried to access internet it gets installed successfully.
Problem is I have to install this in another server with no internet

Please advice

Comment: What happens if you run `./python -m pip list | grep setuptools`?

Comment: it does display setuptools. e.g. 
[root@lorenz Python-3.11.3]# ./python -m pip list | grep setuptools
setuptools 65.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a JAX issue: it looks like `pip` is simply not designed to install packages offline; see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4753

See [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline) for some suggestions on how you might proceed.