# ERROR: No matching distribution found for maturin<2,>=1

Tags: python, pip, maturin

Due to our company's IT policy, I am unable to install Python packages directly from external repositories. Instead, I first have to download the packages to my local directory before using pip for installation.

I attempted to install the pydantic-core package (version 2.14.5) from an archive using the following pip command:

*pip install --user pydantic_core-2.14.5.tar.gz*

However, this resulted in the following error message:

**ERROR: No matching distribution found for maturin<2,>=1**

The issue is that I already have maturin 1.4.0 installed on my system. Also, my path variable is set to point to this executable directory: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\maturin.exe.

Despite having the appropriate version installed, pip seems unable to recognize/find it.

Is there any way to work around this issue and get pydantic-core installed from the archive file?

Thank you.

I tried to use conda instead of pip but it seems conda is not the best option, it gives me a lot of error messages.

Comment: Just in case, I am using Python 3.11.5 that came with Anaconda.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 On a host connected to the Net run the same Python on the same platform (OS + processor); run `pip download pydantic`; this downloads all recursive dependencies. Move the downloaded packages to your offline host and run `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/packages`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline