# Installation apache airflow OFFLINe

Tags: python, pip, airflow, pypi

I'm trying to install Apache Airflow on a CentOS 7 server that doesn't have internet access. Here's the approach I've taken:

I used pip download apache-airflow on a machine with internet access to download the Apache Airflow package and its dependencies.
Then, I transferred the downloaded .whl files to the CentOS 7 server.
On the CentOS 7 server, I attempted to install Apache Airflow using pip install --find-links /path/to/downloaded/files.
However, during installation, I encountered errors indicating that Python packages couldn't be found.

Could anyone advise on the correct procedure for installing Apache Airflow in this scenario? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Get all the dependencies required for apache-airflow in your online machine into a requirement.txt file and then follow the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/23326889 to download the dependencies first and then move the directory into your offline machine and do the installation there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline