Problems to install PyAutoGUI : setuptools ERROR
I'm encountering troubles intalling PyAutoGUI on a machine without internet.
I've downloaded PyAutoGUI 0.9.54 (the tar.gz file) and the following error apprear :
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
I've tried with several versions of setuptools (including the 40.8.0) and the error still appear.
Has anyone encountered this problem?
I'm using python 3.8.6 and pip 24.0 on a Windows machine

"I've tried with several versions of setuptools" Can you show us what ways you've tried? For offline installation you need to download all dependencies and move them to the offline host: first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline
